# Super class doesn't have a zero argument constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a base class in a data model.

I have a base class of Symptoms and I want to add Headache as an extension of Symptom

Right now this is my code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Symptom {
  final String id;
  final String path;
  final DateTime startTime;
  final String? type;

  String get patientId => path.split('/')[1];

  Symptom({
    required this.id,
    required this.path,
    required this.startTime,
    this.type,
  });

  factory Symptom.fromJson(
    String id,
    String path,
    Map<String, Object?> doc,
  ) {
    final start = doc['startTime'] as Timestamp;
    return Symptom(
      id: id,
      path: path,
      startTime: start.toDate(),
      type: doc['type'] as String?,
    );
  }

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'startTime': startTime,
      'type': type,
    };
  }
}

class Headache extends Symptom {
  int? intensity;
  DateTime? endTime;
  List<String> symptoms;
  List<String> effects;
  Map<String, int> medications;
  bool? medsEffective;
  String? notes;

  Duration? get duration => endTime?.difference(startTime);

  double get hours {
    final inHours = duration?.inHours ?? 0;
    final inMins = duration?.inMinutes ?? 0;
    if (inHours < 1) {
      return inMins / 60;
    } else {
      return inHours.toDouble();
    }
  }

  Headache({
    this.intensity,
    this.medsEffective = false,
    this.endTime,
    this.notes,
    this.symptoms = const [],
    this.effects = const [],
    this.medications = const {},
  });

  factory Headache.fromJson(
    String id,
    String path,
    Map<String, Object?> doc,
  ) {
    final start = doc['startTime'] as Timestamp;
    final end = doc['endTime'] as Timestamp?;

    final tempMeds = doc['medications'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Headache(
      intensity: doc['intensity'] as int?,
      notes: doc['notes'] as String?,
      endTime: end?.toDate(),
      medsEffective: (doc['medsEffective'] as bool?),
      symptoms:
          (doc['symptoms'] as List).map((item) => item as String).toList(),
      effects: (doc['effects'] as List).map((item) => item as String).toList(),
      // ignore: unnecessary_lambdas
      medications: tempMeds.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value)),
    );
  }

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'intensity': intensity,
      'notes': notes,
      'endTime': endTime,
      'symptoms': symptoms,
      'medsEffective': medsEffective,
      'effects': effects,
      'medications': medications,
    };
  }
}
```

When I try to do

```
Headache({
    this.intensity,
    this.medsEffective = false,
    this.endTime,
    this.notes,
    this.symptoms = const [],
    this.effects = const [],
    this.medications = const {},
  });
```

It gives me an error

> The superclass 'Symptom' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
> Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'Symptom', or explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'Symptom'

I am wondering how to fix this but also why is this error coming up and why does it need a zero argument constructor. Is extending a base class of a data model a good practice or should I shy away from this and make an entirely separate data model for headaches separate from symptoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't explicitly call the super constructor in the constructor of child class, the compiler will try to implicitly call the default constructor of the super class (which, in this case, would be `Symptom()`).

Since you've defined a `Symptom` constructor that takes several arguments, there is no automatic default constructor for the class, so the `Headache` constructor is unable to initialize the fields of the super class.

You can resolve this by having your `Headache` constructor take additional arguments to initialize the super class:

```
Headache({
  this.intensity,
  this.medsEffective = false,
  this.endTime,
  this.notes,
  this.symptoms = const [],
  this.effects = const [],
  this.medications = const {},
  required String id,
  required String path,
  required DateTime startTime,
  String? type,
}): super(
  id: id, 
  path: path,
  startTime: startTime,
  type: type,
);
```

Comment: That fixed it! Now I only have the question of do I have to specify that I'm querying firebase for headaches or could I query just for symptoms and if it is a headache that gets returned I'll use this headache sub class but if it is something else then I wont?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Michael's answer regarding the error you are receiving, but I want to comment on the how you are structuring your objects.

I would make a generic `Illness` class, with the name of the illness (e.g. "Headache") as a property so that you don't need to predefine every possible type of illness. Then I would suggest that `Symptom` should have a property field that holds an `Illness` object. If you want to constrain the types of illnesses, you can make the illness an `enum` that defines all possible illness types.

If you decide you have a good reason for directly creating classes for each specific illness, create an abstract `Illness` class and `Headache` should inherit from it so that all of the illnesses are interchangeable throughout the application.